# How to test for useEffect inside a custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

So I'm pretty new to testing with react. I have a custom hook that I am calling inside a component. I am using the `renderHook` methods from `react-hook-testing-library`.

I need to test if the methods inside `useEffect` inside the custom hook are called. I cant seem to figure this out.

In another case, I need to figure out if `trackPdpGtm` is not called.

**Note:** The hook does not return any data. This is mainly for sending analytics information.

**Current Approach:**

**usePdpGtm.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { trackPdpGtm } from 'utils/gtm/pdpGtmUtils';
import _ from 'utils/lodashImports';

export default function useGtmPdp(data = {}) {
  console.log('are you getting called?');
  const { relatedProducts, results, priceInfo, breadcrumbs } = data;
  const relatedProductsLoaded = _.get(relatedProducts, 'relatedProductsLoaded');
  useEffect(() => {
     if (relatedProductsLoaded) {
         trackPdpGtm(data);
     }
  }, [relatedProductsLoaded, results, priceInfo, breadcrumbs]);
}
```

I need to test if `trackPdpGtm` are called. Also need to check that its not called in another test case.

**gtm.test.js**

```
import { renderHook, cleanup, act } from 'react-hooks-testing-library';
import usePdpGtm from 'utils/hooks/gtmHooks/usePdpGtm';
import useListPageGtm from 'utils/hooks/gtmHooks/useListPageGtm';
import { trackPdpGtm } from 'utils/gtm/pdpGtmUtils';
import { trackListPageGtm } from 'utils/gtm/plpGtmUtils';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { ProductDescriptionComponent } from 'components/business/ProductDescription/ProductDescriptionComponent';

jest.mock('utils/hooks/gtmHooks/usePdpGtm');
jest.mock('utils/hooks/gtmHooks/useListPageGtm');
jest.mock('utils/gtm/pdpGtmUtils');
jest.mock('utils/gtm/plpGtmUtils');

trackPdpGtm.mockImplementation = jest.fn();
// ALSO TRIED trackPdpGtm.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
trackListPageGtm.mockImplementation(() => console.log('adadada'));

describe('analytics helper', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  it('should fire usePdpGtm Hook', async (done) => {
    const pdpData = {
      relatedProducts: {
        collectionProducts: [],
        relatedProductsLoaded: true
      },
      productInfo: {
        variants: [{}],
        breadcrumbs: [{}],
        serviceWarrantyDetails: {
          services: [],
          warranties: [{}]
        }
      },
      priceInfo: [{}],
      breadcrumbs: [{}]
    };
    const { result } = renderHook(() => usePdpGtm(pdpData));
    //THIS IS FAILING
    expect(trackPdpGtm).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();
  });

   it('should fire usePdpGtm Hook without data', () => {
     const { result } = renderHook(() => usePdpGtm(undefined));
    
     // NEED TO TEST IF trackPdpGtm is NOT called. (also failing)

     expect(trackPdpGtm).toNotBeCalled();
     expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();
   });

});
```

Also tried using `trackGtmPdp.mock.calls.length.toBe(1)`.

The `usePdpGtm` hook is called inside `ProductDescriptionComponent` and receives an object as its argument.

**Note:**  The custom hook is not running during the test. I am not sure but the console.log statements inside are not printed while the test is running.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: see also https://epicreact.dev/how-to-test-react-use-effect/

Comment: thanks but this doesn't cover what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget to clear the `mock.calls` and `mock.instances` properties of `trackPdpGtm` function mock. That's why your second test case fails. You can use [jest.clearAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks) to clear it in `afterEach` hook.

E.g.

`usePdpGtm.ts`:

```
// @ts-nocheck
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { trackPdpGtm } from './pdpGtmUtils';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function useGtmPdp(data = {}) {
  console.log('are you getting called?');
  const { relatedProducts, results, priceInfo, breadcrumbs } = data;
  const relatedProductsLoaded = _.get(relatedProducts, 'relatedProductsLoaded');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (relatedProductsLoaded) {
      trackPdpGtm(data);
    }
  }, [relatedProductsLoaded, results, priceInfo, breadcrumbs]);
}
```

`pdpGtmUtils.ts`:

```
export function trackPdpGtm(data) {
  console.log('real track pdp gtm implementation');
}
```

`usePdpGtm.test.ts`:

```
import { renderHook, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import usePdpGtm from './usePdpGtm';
import { trackPdpGtm } from './pdpGtmUtils';

jest.mock('./pdpGtmUtils');

describe('analytics helper', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    cleanup();
  });

  it('should fire usePdpGtm Hook', () => {
    const pdpData = {
      relatedProducts: {
        collectionProducts: [],
        relatedProductsLoaded: true,
      },
      productInfo: {
        variants: [{}],
        breadcrumbs: [{}],
        serviceWarrantyDetails: {
          services: [],
          warranties: [{}],
        },
      },
      priceInfo: [{}],
      breadcrumbs: [{}],
    };
    const { result } = renderHook(() => usePdpGtm(pdpData));
    expect(trackPdpGtm).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();
  });

  it('should fire usePdpGtm Hook without data', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => usePdpGtm(undefined));
    expect(trackPdpGtm).not.toBeCalled();
    expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65703648/usePdpGtm.test.ts
  analytics helper
    ✓ should fire usePdpGtm Hook (28 ms)
    ✓ should fire usePdpGtm Hook without data (4 ms)

  console.log
    are you getting called?

      at Object.useGtmPdp [as default] (examples/65703648/usePdpGtm.ts:7:11)

  console.log
    are you getting called?

      at Object.useGtmPdp [as default] (examples/65703648/usePdpGtm.ts:7:11)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |   91.67 |      100 |   66.67 |   91.67 |                   
 pdpGtmUtils.ts |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
 usePdpGtm.ts   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.167 s
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, I am facing a strange issue now. Both the cases are failing but are now opposite of each other. 

For first test case I am getting: `Expected no of calls: 1, received: 0`
For the second test case:  `Expected no of calls: 0, received: 1`

I donot understand the reason for this. Am i missing something 
@slideshowp2

Comment: Update: I added a delay before the first expect statement executes in the first test case. Basically a promise that resolves with setTimeout. All the test cases started working as expected. But clearMocks should have solved this problem. I cant seem to wrap my head around this concept. Need to learn the fundamentals I guess.